# How to add service-account to instance template with deployment manager

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-deployment-manager

I am trying to create simple VM based on example given in here[1](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/deploymentmanager-samples/tree/master/examples/v2/single_vm/python).
I want to add custom service account [2](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts) to this VM. 
My config looks something like this

```
def GenerateConfig(context):
"""Create instance with disks."""

resources = [{
    'type': 'compute.v1.instance',
    'name': 'vm-' + context.env['deployment'],
    'properties': {
        'zone': context.properties['zone'],
        'disks': [{
            'deviceName': 'boot',
            'type': 'PERSISTENT',
            'boot': True,
            'autoDelete': True,
            'initializeParams': {
                'diskName': 'disk-' + context.env['deployment'],
             }
        }],
        'networkInterfaces': [{
            'network': '...',       
            'subnetwork': '...',                       
            'no-address': True,
        }],
        'tags':{
            'items': [context.env['deployment']]
        },
        'service-account': ''.join(['custom-compute@',
                                    context.env['project'],
                                    '.iam.gserviceaccount.com']),
        'scopes': ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only',
                   'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/logging.write',
                   'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/monitoring.write',
                   'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/trace.append']

    }
}]
return {'resources': resources}
```

I am able to successfully create the deployment. However when I describe the newly created instance it doesn't have any "service-account" associated with the vm.

I couldn't find any example of adding service-account to Deployment manager template. I have also tried to use "serviceAccount" key instead of 'service-account' without any success. 
Does anyone knows what I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

I found the reference [DM reference docs](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/beta/instances).
The required changes were

```
'serviceAccounts': [{
    'email': '....',
    'scopes': '...' 
 }]
```